# Old Will Shortz puzzle

Tags: word, wordplay

This one should also should be easy.  You shouldn't have trouble with this one.

Which actress is a "sweet talkin'" girl?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Kate Winslet

Because

> Her name is an anagram of 'sweet talkin'.

Comment: Reminds me of [Jeremy's Iron](http://www.simpsonsworld.com/video/311649859552).

Comment: Correct.  Did you see I gave credit to Will Shortz?  (It might have been from one of his readers, for that matter.)  Good job!

Comment: Nice anagram, but to pass muster as a crossword clue it needs an anagram ind -- perhaps "Sort of..." or "Unusual...". Or perhaps even something like "Performing..." if you'd accept that as indicating that the letters move about. Did Will Shortz really use the clue as given in the OP, as a crossword clue?

Comment: @RosieF  It is not tagged as a crossword or cryptic crossword.